# How to pass a function as an argument to a destination fragment - Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment, android-navigation

I have a class that extends `DialogFragment` that I'd like to use as a destination in my navigation graph so that I can open it like I would any other fragment.  I'd like to pass functions as arguments to my `DialogFragment` class to be used in the positive and negative button listeners.  In this case they would be functions from the calling Fragment.

So, is it possible to pass functions as arguments to a Navigation Component destination, or is there another way to go about doing this.  Does the DialogFragment need its own ViewModel?

Comment: "In this case they would be functions from the calling Fragment's ViewModel" -- then why not use a shared `ViewModel`, perhaps one scoped to the nav graph? See [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v1.0/NukeFromOrbit) for an example of a `DialogFragment` using a nav graph-scoped `ViewModel` to communicate actions to another fragment. "is it possible to pass functions as arguments to a Navigation Component destination" -- I don't think so, as they might not work well after a configuration change.

Comment: I just looked back at the code, and they actually aren't from the viewmodel, sorry.  I've edited the post.  The functions I'd like to pass in make use of things from the calling fragment like a service, and view elements.  Passing a reference to the dialog would be easiest, but I'm not sure if there's a way to do that (or achieve something similar)

Comment: "they actually aren't from the viewmodel" -- you could still use a shared `ViewModel` to let the calling fragment know about the actions taken in the dialog.

Comment: You're right, I'll give that a shot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up doing this was by having a shared ViewModel, as @CommonsWare suggested.

The ViewModel is setup like this:

```
class ViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) { }
```

and it is instantiated like this, using `requireActivity()` in both fragments that use it to make sure that it acts as a singleton, since those fragments share a parent activity.

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: What if the intent is to bundle the fragment as part of an SDK, and you want the integrator to be able to show the fragment using navigation and have some kind of callback on a button tap? I wish they would just let us pass a callback into the navigation bundle. The only way I can think to accomplish this is by not showing the fragment via navigation.